# Content is not updating while using phrasing gem in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using phrasing gem to edit the content of the sites in browser,

am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2

I have installed the gem (Phrasing) and done the following steps,

Step 1:

```
rake phrasing:install
```

Step 2:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Step 3:

```
module PhrasingHelper

   def can_edit_phrases?
      current_user.has_role :admin?
   end
end
```

Step 4: Included the phrasing html initializer at the top of body

```
<% render 'phrasing/initializer' %>
```

Step 5: Included javascript and css also.

Step 6: Then i have included below line in my view file

```
<%= phrase('my-first-phrase') %>
```

Now, i was able to edit the text but it is not getting saved. When i refresh the page the edited text is not there (only old text is there).
Error am facing in javascript console is:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) jquery.js?body=1:8707
send jquery.js?body=1:8707
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:8137
savePhraseViaAjax phrasing.js?body=1:89
(anonymous function) phrasing.js?body=1:70
```

What i am missing here. Could anyone help me in this.

Comment: can you please tell me the EXACT version of jquery you are using?

Comment: My exact jquery version is 1.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery log doesnt seems to have any issues. I guess it should be `<%=` instead of `<%` while rendering initializer or might be some routing problem.

Comment: Thanks. yes as you said, It is a routing problem, i have changed in phrasing.rb initializers as,

Phrasing.setup do |config|
  config.route = 'p/ph/phrasing'
end

Now, the problem is solved.